# Wrapping text around full page tables

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a full page table that I want to position at a particular place in my document, but this is the middle of a paragraph.  I can't seem to make Word wrap my paragraph text before / after the table using page breaks, text-wrapping breaks or section breaks, and if I manually cut and paste enough of my text to make it appear on the page after my table then the text before the table isn't justified (the last line doesn't extend all the way to the right margin) - what am I missing to achieve this?!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the wording here. If it's a "full page" table, can't you simply add a page break at the end of one full page of text, have the "full page table" cover the next page, then have the rest of the text continue from the beginning of the third page? Something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jkZKM.png) perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, but I haven't got it working (yet)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of

[image: paragraph with last line not fully justified]

gets you

[image: paragraph with last line fully justified, but on new page]

then try turning off “Widow/Orphan control” for that paragraph.  If that doesn’t help, try applying the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> one line up:

[image: paragraph with last line before page break fully justified]

And then can you just move the “Welfare, and secure the” line to page 3?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean; you’re getting this:

[image: paragraph with last line not fully justified]

Try typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end:

[image: paragraph with last line fully justified]

On the other hand, if you don’t really mean full-page, but only full-page-width, have you considered using a Text Box?

[image: paragraph split by a Text Box]

Comment: I do mean full page, and not full width.  When I use `Shift` +`Enter`, the final line on Page 1 actually appears at the top of page 2, but does appear justified.

Comment: So, can you move that line from page 1 to page 3?

Comment: Yes, but the last line on P1 still never appears justified. I have fixed it for now as an edit I made to that paragraph meant that the last line on P1 did extend (almost) fully across the page, and so the fact it's not justified is not as obvious

Comment: I think I might understand what’s happening.  Please see [my new answer](http://superuser.com/a/497250).