# Align text left for one line in paragraph only

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In Word, when I select a line in a paragraph (the last line)  and click `Ctrl+L` (Align Text Left), the whole paragraph is aligned to the left, not just my selected line. I want to justify the rest of the paragraph both left and right

Is there a way to do this with just the selected line, so that the remaining lines in the paragraph are not affected?

[image]

EDIT: I found the solutions. After the last line of the paragraph I must press `enter` for that last line to be left aligned, otherwise that last line will still be `Justified` and looks ugly if it's only a few words

[image]

Comment: Think in the paragraph options, there is an option to effect selected or whole paragraph.  By default, its the whole paragraph but i think you can turn it off either ad-hoc or through options.  Get back to you on specifics.

Comment: Did some quick testing out on a document im working on and if you want a one line indent, you are slightly SOL.  Work around is to define your left, root, right indent markers in the ruler.  Good read, [Document Link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=word%202010%20change%20left%20indent%20of%20line%20in%20paragraph&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&ved=0CFkQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gcflearnfree.org%2Fword2010%2F8%2Fprint&ei=5Xy_UPTPJIeY8gTvhIDAAQ&usg=AFQjCNHBjMnwX5GK3FI0xPaNugmBEu6Zdg)

Answer (score 3):

> Many people use justified paragraphs in their documents. These types of paragraphs align both the left and right edges of the text in the paragraph, much like what is done in many books and magazine articles. If you are one of these people, you may have noticed that when you add a manual line break (Shift+Enter) in a justified paragraph, ***Word forces the line to the full width of the paragraph. This can look very strange and ruin the appearance of your text.***
>
> ***You can avoid this problem***, however, by making sure that you ***enter a tab character just before the manual line break.*** When you do, ***Word makes the line with the tab left aligned, ignoring the justification alignment you applied to the whole paragraph.***

Source: [Using Manual Line Breaks with Justified Paragraphs by Allen Wyatt](https://word.tips.net/T001324_Using_Manual_Line_Breaks_with_Justified_Paragraphs.html)

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing that causes *the last line of a paragraph* to be aligned anything other than Left?

Comment: I want to justify the rest of the paragraph both left and right

Comment: Are you saying that the paragraph is “Justified” (a.k.a. fully justified), with left margin and right margin lined up?  The last line should still be left-aligned already.  Please explain what you are trying to do better.  A picture is worth a thousand words; consider posting screen images.  You might also want to look at [this question](http://superuser.com/q/492871/150988).

Comment: oh I found the solutions. After the last line of the paragraph I must press `enter` for that last line to be left aligned, otherwise that last line will still be `Justified` and looks ugly if it's only a few words

Comment: Feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer, since it seems to have led you to the answer.  BTW, what were you doing: typing (Shift+Enter) at the ends of paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to align only a sentence. The property you are adjusting is a property of the *paragraph*.

[image]

As you have found, it changes the entire paragraph. You might try using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move it.